# Solving Three equations for 3 Unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Today I have a question and I am really curious to know about this.

**Question:**
$$ 16y+39z+50zy=0$$
$$ 85x-78z+95zx=0$$
$$ 85x+32y+70xy=0$$

$$\text{Are The Equations like these can be solve for unknowns? If not Why?If so How?}$$
I derived those from these:
$$ 1/x+1/y-1/z=-1$$
$$ 4/x+3/y+2/z=16$$
$$ 2/x-2/y-3/z=5$$

Comment: Assuming your derivation is correct, now plug in $1/x=u,1/y=v,1/z=w$ and solve normally. But note that in this way you'll miss the solution $(0,0,0)$

Comment: If its is like this,how to solve?

$$ 16y+39z+50zy=0$$
$$ 85x-78z+95zx=0$$
$$ 85x+32y+70xy=0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you derived the system of the equations correctly, you then get a normal 3x3 system equation with first-degree set of variables. This is a common linear algebra problem and can be solved in a ton of ways.

First of all, express $\frac{1}{x} = i , \frac{1}{y} = j , \frac{1}{z} = k$

Then you will have the following :

$ i + j + k = 1, 4i + 3j + 2k = 16, 2i - 2j - 3k = 5 $

In order to show that these can be solved or not, you can apply the Gauss Method on the matrix of their coefficients. Be careful after that, on probable solutions that may not apply for the starting fractions ($\frac{1}{x}$etc )

Comment: My questions was not that actually.  If we have to the solve thr eqution in this form how to do it?


$$ 16y+39z+50zy=0$$
$$ 85x-78z+95zx=0$$
$$ 85x+32y+70xy=0$$

Comment: You do it the exactly reverse way. Or you can do it the grinding way by solving for $x,y,z$ and plugging them into each every one, but there are a lot of operations there. It's correct thought. Also a hint : Geometrically, all your 3 equations describe hyperbolas, sou you are trying to find their intersection points (if any exist).

Comment: So i have to graph it in three dimension to solve.(intersect point)

Comment: Geometrically yes, every system of equations is the finding of the intersection point of the curves that each equations describes. But that's not possible to do at most times by drawing, because you would have to draw things in the $\mathbb R^3$ which isn't easy if not impossible in the paper 2 dimensions.

Comment: But if you are bothered enough and you can't think of anything else, you can just solve each equation for $x=... , y=..., z=...$ and plug them into the other ones and find the solution that way.

Comment: so i have to this with any online graph webs?

Comment: No. I just told you that you can solve each equation with respect to a parameter and plug it in the other ones ....

Comment: OKAY AND THANKS!!!!

Comment: No problem ! But know that in that way you will have to be careful not to do any mistakes, because there are a lot of operations. But as I said, since you have the starting system equation where you can solve that or even derive the "hard" one to the starting one by applying algebraic modifications :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have to solve $$ 16y+39z+50zy=0\tag 1$$
$$ 85x-78z+95zx=0\tag 2$$
$$ 85x+32y+70xy=0\tag 3$$ use $(2)$ and solve it for $z$ to get $$z=-\frac{85 x}{95 x-78}\tag 4$$ (which assumes $95x-78\neq 0 $ )

Do the same using $(3)$ for $y$ to get $$y=-\frac{85 x}{70 x+32}\tag 5$$ (which assumes $70x+32\neq 0 $ )

Use $(4)$ and $(5)$ in $(1)$ which will lead, after simplification to the beautiful $$0=0$$ So, your system has solutions which depend on an arbitrary value of $x$. You can notice that the trivial solution $x=y=z=0$ is a result of the above.

**Edit**

If the first equation was $$a y+b z+c zy=0$$ reducing to same denominator would lead to $$x^2 (-8075 a-5950 b+7225 c)+x (6630 a-2720 b)=0$$ which shows that $x=0$ is always a solution, the other one being $$x=\frac{2 (39 a-16 b)}{5 (19 a+14 b-17 c)}$$ which is again $0$ if, as in your case, $39a=16b$ and very problematic if $19a+14b-17c=0$.

Comment: Solution are: $x=\frac{1}{4.4}\space y=\frac{1}{-2.48} \space z=\frac{1}{2.92}$

Comment: @Rahim. If, in the solution I wrote, you plug $x=\frac{10}{44}$, you get $y=-\frac{25}{62}$ and $z=\frac{25}{73}$ which are your numbers. These are the solutions for the second system you wrote in your post.

Comment: Can we find these number by using first system in my post?